# Is there a way to make a button function, that when pressed changes the title of another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I'm trying to make a music app, where on the frontpage there's buttons. When you press one of the buttons, a card pops up. I want the cards title to be depended by which button have been pressed. I'm using react for my project. Is there any way this is possible?

I have this function for my buttons

```
export function GenreButton({ text }) {
    return <StyledGenreButton>{text}</StyledGenreButton>


export function Button (){


return (
    <>
        <Wrapper>
            <GenreButton text='Country' />
            <GenreButton text='Disco' />
            <GenreButton text='Funk' /> 
            <GenreButton text='House' /> 
       
        </Wrapper>
    </>
)
```

}

And for my card component:

```
const CardTitle2 = () => {
    const [cardTitle, setCardTitle] = useState ('string')
    return <StyledCardTitle onClick={() => setCardTitle('New Title')}>{cardTitle}</StyledCardTitle>
```

So far, i've tried importing the Card component into my Button component, added an onClick property to my GenreButton function.

```
export function GenreButton({ text, onClick }) {
    return <StyledGenreButton>{[text, onClick]}</StyledGenreButton>
```

And then inserting an onClick onto one of the GenreButtons in the return statement.

Now i know, that my card title will be changed from 'string' to 'New Title', when i press the title. But is it possible that i can change the title of my card to be equal to my string input from the button?

Comment: If you have generally two or more components that are siblings (no parent child relation) then you should lift state up i.e. create one component wrapping them both and state should be there. see: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured out how to do it.

```
export function Button (){ 
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
function GenreButton({ text }) {
    return <StyledGenreButton onClick={() => setTitle(text)}>{text}</StyledGenreButton>
}


<Wrapper>
            <GenreButton text='Country'/>
            <GenreButton text='Disco' />
            <GenreButton text='Electro' /> 
</Wrapper>
            <CardWrapper>
                <CardTitle title={title} />
            </CardWrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should lift state up, e.g lift state up to your home page:

```
const HomePage = () => {
   const [title, setTitle] = useState('string')

   return (
     <Card title={title}/>
     <Buttons setTitle={setTitle}/>
   )
}
```

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Hmm... It doesn't seem to fix my issue. Maybe i am doing something wrong...